# Using printf() function in PHP to print negative integer with unsigned format specifier

Tags: php, printf, unsigned-integer

I have the following code:

```
<?php
  $num1 = -12;
  printf("%%u = %u<br>",$num1);
?>
```

Output:

```
%u = 4294967284
```

I am unable to understand the reason behind such output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any unsigned type means >= 0 values.

Here is what the php docs say:

**The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 5.0.5, and minimum value using the constant PHP_INT_MIN since PHP 7.0.0.**

I'm running it on Windows x64, so the value to PHP_INT_MAX will be a integer 64 bit long (9223372036854775807). From the value you are reporting, you probably have a 32 bit system.

So, for your system the signed 32 bit integer values range from -2147483648 to 2147483647. For unsigned values it goes from 0 to 4294967295.

Your value of 4294967284 is 4294967295 - 12 + 1.

Bottom line: you can safe cast regular int to unsigned int if it's a positive value. If it's a negative value, the cast will result in value generated by the above formula (MAX_UINT - value + 1). Signed and unsigned types are only compatible with positive values.

You can use an if clause for a proper signed format specifier for accurate printing of values.

Hope this clears out the problem.

Comment: You said PHP does not support unsigned int. But again you are saying for unsigned values it goes from 0 to 4294967295

Comment: I did not say that PHP does not support unsigned int. The official documentation said that (the bolded text is from the official PHP docs). They do not offer native support for unsigned int because until version 7, php did not have typed declarations. They somehow emulate unsigned int using the formula I mentioned earlier. This is what I wanted to be clear. And the fact that signed and unsigned types do not have the same value range.

Answer (score 1):

`%u` stands for unsigned. You are creating an overflow if you put in a negative number. Thus resulting an this big number.

The number in memory is just bits. If you let it interpret as unsigned the first bit is no longer the sign, but part of the number.

What you want is:

```
$num1 = -12;
printf("%%u = %u<br>",abs($num1));
```

It would also work with `%d`

```
printf("%%d = %d<br>",abs($num1));
```

Comment: I know how to bring correct result. It was just curiosity that propelled me to ask this question. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain the concept of memory overflow in more details?